# User auth check before accessing sub domain URL - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, subdomain

I'm trying to check if the user is logged in or not when accessing subdomain, if not then enforce the user to login into the main domain.
Below is the process which I followed.
Changes I made in `.env` file as 
`SESSION_DOMAIN=mac.local`
`SESSION_DRIVER=database`

and ran the migration for sessions using `php artisan session:table`.

Menu link:

`<a href="{{ route('asset',['account' =>'dev']) }}">Dev subdomain</a>`

Routes:

```
Route::domain('{account}.' . env('SESSION_DOMAIN'))->group(function () {
        Route::get('/', 'HomeController@subdomainAsset')->name('asset');
    });
```

I have a fresh laravel project installed at `dev.mac.local`.

`dev.mac.local` is loading even I did not login into `mac.local`.

How do I keep a check to ensure the user should log in before they access this subdomain `dev.mac.local`, if not return a message to log in before access this subdomain?

Any suggestions, please.

Comment: You have to apply middleware auth on your route. Then i will not be accessible and will automatically redirect to login page.

Comment: @GeorgeMylonas Yes, I had set up the middleware too. But still not working :(